# No renderiza el layout en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, xml

Estoy comenzando con Android Studio y me surgió el siguiente problema. A la hora de crear un proyecto nuevo con el IDE, la parte gráfica me sale de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se carga ni el texto por defecto ni me deja poner otro elemento. Si intento cargar otro componente se posiciona en una esquina fuera del constraintLayout.

Esto me empezó a suceder de la nada. Debido a que al principio me dejaba crear proyectos correctamente sin ningún problema, ya busqué soluciones y solo encontre algunas como reiniciar el IDE, reiniciar el pc, etc, pero ninguna de ellas funcionó.

Código XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#510808"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías comprobar que en el fichero "build.gradle (:app)" tienes la dependencia:
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'

La versión de "constraintlayout" depende de tu entorno, normalmente te sugiere la más reciente en base a la versión de "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0"

Después comprueba que en el fichero "gradle.properties" tienes puesto:
"android.useAndroidX=true"

Los archivos están en:

[image: Estuctura]

> Te recomiendo que revises este enlace para entenderlo bien:
> [Enlace a Developer Android](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout?hl=es-419)
> En esa WEB encontrarás lo necesario para empezar a desarrollar en Android, tanto con Java como con Kotlin.

Comment: Me aseguré de que eso estuviera y si. Las borre, sincronicé y volví a instalarlas y sigue apareciendo el error.  Muchas gracias por responder!

Comment: Habría escrito directamente un comentario, pero es que no podría, por eso puse una respuesta directamente.
Creo que los parents no los tienes bien, prueba a cambiar esto:
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
Por esto:
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

Comment: Ya encontré la solución, simplemente cambié `//implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'` por `implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta4"`. Gracias por responder, fue de gran aporte :)

Comment: Me alegro que te sirviese de ayuda, si lo ves conveniente, marca la respuesta como valida.